# VMWARE Player - Can't shrink disk

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-player, compact-disc, limited-access

I have VMWARE Player (15.5.6 build-16341506), and a Win10/32bit guest OS.
Host is Win10/64 bit.

It is more than 127 GB in the host filesystem.

I deleted the old Windows versions from the guest to clean up. I deleted the pagefile.
I moved all files to the beginning with MyDefrag. I filled the free space with zeroes.
The guest usage is only "70 GB", but the host shows 127 GB.

Then I tried to defrag / compact from host menu.
These two functions are too fast - and the size don't change!

I read that I need to prepare the compact from the guest VMWARE tools.
Then I updated it, but it is only an "About dialog", nothing more!
I have no subpages in the dialog! It has no submenu.

Somebody wrote somewhere that I need to use vmware disk manager exe directly.

In this player I don't have vmware file with "disk" substring.

It seems to be Player have very limited functions.
I think it's based corp. policy - who pays could plays - so maybe all specials disabled in Player which available in Workstation or paid softwares.

Is it true, or it is only a bug in my machine?
The other people who has player - do you also have these limitations?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Yes, the player has very limited functions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are [a number of ways](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/win10-secure-install/#DRI) to reduce the size of a Windows system. It sounds like you have taken some of those steps, or at any rate you feel that 70GB is an appropriate size for the guest system.

Your question, as I understand it, is how to shrink the size of the VM so that it takes not much more than 70GB of disk space on the host system. It is true that the VMware Player GUI does not offer a shrink option. But as pointed out in [a Server Fault discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/356681/vmplayer-virtual-disk-shrinking-compacting-defragmenting), there is still a command line option.

Combining information from both answers offered in that discussion, the recommended procedure begins by running two commands in an elevated administrator `cmd` window inside the running Windows VM: first `dfrgui`, and then `VMwareToolboxCmd.exe disk shrink c:\`. The latter should be run in the folder where the VMwareToolboxCmd.exe file is located. By default, that will be C:\Program Files\VMWare\VMTools. The advice is then to run `dfrgui` again. ([Miklix](https://www.miklix.com/virtualization/shrink-virtual-disk-in-vmware-player/) explains the `shrink` command for a Linux system, where defragmentation would be less of an issue.)

Then power down the VM, go into its Settings in VMware Player, and use its Defragment and Compact options. Finally, shut down VMware Player and run `dfrgui` on the host system.

Those seem to be the recommended steps. I suspect the `VMwareToolboxCmd.exe disk shrink c:\` command will make the most significant difference in your case. But the other steps can’t hurt; and if they don’t add much, they also probably won’t take very long.

For those who want to shrink the VM primarily to make the smallest possible backup, my experience is that the compression tool (e.g., 7-Zip or WinRAR, run in the host system) will do approximately the same thing. I seem to wind up with compressed images of relatively similar size, regardless of whether I take the steps just suggested or leave it to the compression tool to squeeze out the unnecessary space.

Comment: Cool solution...!
This is the main statement I needed: VMwareToolboxCmd.exe disk shrink c:\

Comment: Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)